# How can I put space between a select and a input in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to put a space between my two elements, my select and my input, but nothing is working, i already tried with             `&#09;` or with a specific style but it's not working.

```
    <a-col
      style=" display: flex;"
    >
        <a-select
          ...
        >
          <a-select-option value="test">test1</a-select-option>     
          ...   
          >
        </a-select>
        <a-input-search
          ....
        />
  </a-col>
```

Anyone have an idea to put space (or empty area) between my two elements ?

Comment: What do you mean a space? Do you mean a literal `&nbsp;`? Do you mean any empty area?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy an empty area. Basically, i just don't want the two elements to stick together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a custom css....
Like :

```
<a-input-search style='padding-right: 12px'
  ....
/>
```